Iptables: Exclude a specific port from being forwarded to the destination
I have the following iptables rule that forwards all incoming traffic to an ip in the local network 10.8.0.2
sudo iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -d 172.31.44.186 -j DNAT --to-destination 10.8.0.2

is there a way I can exclude port 27 from being forwarded? (or force it to be "forwarded" to 127.0.0.1)

Not unless you "split" the rule into two or more rules. In other words, you'll need to add rules for the protocol(s) where the port needs to be excluded. Assuming you want to exclude the port for both TCP and UDP:
sudo iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -d 172.31.44.186 -p tcp ! --dport 27 -j DNAT --to-destination 10.8.0.2
sudo iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -d 172.31.44.186 -p udp ! --dport 27 -j DNAT --to-destination 10.8.0.2
sudo iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -d 172.31.44.186 -j DNAT --to-destination 10.8.0.2

Note that there are traffics that are of neither TCP or UDP, hence the "original" rule is kept as the "fallback". Also the order of the rules matters. If the original rule is appended (-A) first (or inserted, i.e., -I, last), then the protocol specific rule(s) won't be matched because the original rule would "catch" all types of -d 172.31.44.186 traffics.
FWIW, probably the more proper way is to have a user-defined chain:
sudo iptables -t nat -N NAME_YOU_LIKE
sudo iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -d 172.31.44.186 -j NAME_YOU_LIKE
sudo iptables -t nat -A NAME_YOU_LIKE -p tcp --dport 27 -j RETURN
sudo iptables -t nat -A NAME_YOU_LIKE -p udp --dport 27 -j RETURN
sudo iptables -t nat -A NAME_YOU_LIKE -j DNAT --to-destination 10.8.0.2

Nothing would be done for traffics that target TCP or UDP port 27 when they traverse the chain (NAME_YOU_LIKE) because of -j RETURN, which would stop them from traversing the chain further and "get them back to" where they jumped (i.e., -j) from (and continue traversal there, unless it was a "goto", i.e. -g, that led them to this chain), while traffics otherwise would be DNAT'd to 10.8.0.2.
(NOTE: if the traffics are not matched by any terminating rule in the user-defined chain, they will go back to where they jump from too. In other words you can see it as there is unconditional -j RETURN at the end that is implied. But that's "irrelevant" in the example, because the -j DNAT rule at the end is an unconditional terminating rule.)
Since user-defined chain does not have any effect unless traffics are made to traverse (i.e., jump or go to) it with a rule in a base chain, with (only) -d 172.31.44.186 -j NAME_YOU_LIKE, only traffics that were (originally) destined at 172.31.44.186 would traverse the user-defined chain. (To state the obvious, you do NOT need to "check" the traffics with -d 172.31.44.186 "again" in the user-defined chain they jumped to.)

If the "exclusion" is not about having an exception in which case the traffics should go to the original destination, but you really want the traffics to be dropped, then you don't need to make any changes in nat/PREROUTING. Instead, you can / should add DROP rules (or REJECT rules; in some opinions / cases that may be a "better" choice) in filter/FORWARD (or filter/INPUT, if the new destination is this host itself):
sudo iptables -t filter -I FORWARD -d 10.8.0.2 -p tcp --dport 27 -j DROP
sudo iptables -t filter -I FORWARD -d 10.8.0.2 -p udp --dport 27 -j DROP

(Similar user-defined chain approach can be adopted if desired.)

P.S. The multiport module offers --dports for you to match multiple port numbers/ranges in a single rule, which may be used to avoid having multiple --dport rules. (Each rule can still be used for only one protocol though.) See iptables-extensions(8) for details.

Thanks, I also have a question, do I need to do a POSTROUTING from 10.8.0.2 172.31.44.186 and why is it needed (if it is)? And do I need to -j it to MASQUERADE at the end? (I keep seeing it in guides so it's unclear)

@Димитрийi0x There's no such thing as "do a POSTROUTING". POSTROUTING is just a base chain like PREROUTING. It's just that it will be traversed at a different stage and it is where some other targets / verdicts like MASQUERADE can be applied to the traffics (after route decision is made; hence "POST"ROUTING. Where you need MASQUERADE (essentially, source NAT) depends on whether this host is the gateway for the possible source addresses of the (DNAT'd) traffics on the 10.8.0.2 host. If it is, you don't need MASQUERADE.

@Димитрийi0x And if you need it, you probably want to make it conditional with -d match, namely sudo iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -d 10.8.0.2 -j MASQUERADE.
